# Why does my list component in React keep the wrong cell upon a delete event even though the underlying data structure is properly changed?

Tags: javascript, list, reactjs

I am trying to write a dynamic table where I can add and delete rows dynamically. Currently I'm running into a problem with my delete button. It seems to delete the proper element from the data structure (according to the dev tools in Chrome) but when the list is rerendered it keeps seems to remove the wrong row. [image: For example here is when I add 3 dummy rows] then [image: this is after I click the top delete button (the a row)] As you can see the proper element is removed from the state but the incorrect row is removed from the list.

Here is the code for my list

```
export class PantryList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


  render(){
    // Loop through the list of items in the pantry
    var Items = this.props.items.map((data, index) => {
      return (
        //Generate a row for each item for the list
        <PantryRow key={index} quantity={data.quantity} name={data.name} rmFunc={this.props.rmFunc} />
      )
    });

    return (
      <div className='PantryItems'>
      {Items}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

which makes many rows like this:

```
export class PantryRow extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleDeleteEvent = this.handleDeleteEvent.bind(this);
    this.name = this.props.name;
    this.quantity = this.props.quantity;
  }

  handleDeleteEvent(event, item){
    if (event.type === "click"){
      // var item = event.currentTarget;
      console.log(item);
      console.log("click happened");
      event.preventDefault();
      this.props.rmFunc(this.name, this.quantity);
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      // Add your component markup and other subcomponent references here.
      <div className='PantryRow' >
      <p>Quantity: {this.quantity}</p>
      <p>Name: {this.name}</p>
      <button
      className="btn btn-default"
      onClick={this.handleDeleteEvent.bind(this)}>Delete</button>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

then when the delete button is pressed this function is called.

```
  removeFromPantry(name, amount){
    var item = {quantity: amount, name:name};

    console.log(item);
    var items = this.state.pantry.filter(function(itm){
      console.log(itm);
      console.log((item.name != itm.name) && (item.quantity != itm.quantity));
      return (item.name != itm.name) && (item.quantity != itm.quantity);
    });

    this.setState({ pantry: items });
    // this.forceUpdate();
  }
```

I believe that this takes the data from the component that threw the event, recreates a JSON object comparable to what is stored in the state, then it filters through the current state and returns updates a state to contain everything except the one that matches the row to be deleted.

Does anybody have any suggestions for why this may be happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be that you're using `index` as the key, you need to use something unique to that data set. Try using `name` if it's unique. Another thing I noticed that you are using `this.name = this.props.name` which is pointless and a big react no-no. Just use `this.props.name`.

Answer (score 0):

You have created components with some properties directly set as properties of the component in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.name = this.props.name;
  this.quantity = this.props.quantity;
}
```

The render function for your component is using these values, not the prop values. The constructor is not called when the components are reused and you see the initial values:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='PantryRow' >
      ...
      <p>Quantity: {this.quantity}</p>
      <p>Name: {this.name}</p>
      ...
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Since you are using the indices as keys, when the `PantryList` is rendered the first time, keys are `[1, 2]`, and items are `[item1, item2]`. When the first element is deleted you will have keys: `[1]` and items: `[item2]`. Key `1` indicates that the first component should be reused. That component is the one constructed with `this.name = this.props.name` for `item1`.

That means the component being rendered using `this.name`, instead of  `this.prop.name`, will render the name of `item1` even tho the `this.props.name` is the name of `item2`.

You should instead reference the value of name and quantity passed in as props:

```js
class PantryList extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className='PantryItems'>
        {this.props.items.map((data, index) => (
          <PantryRow 
            key={index} 
            name={data.name} 
            quantity={data.quantity} 
            rmFunc={this.props.rmFunc} 
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class PantryRow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleDeleteEvent = this.handleDeleteEvent.bind(this);
  }

  handleDeleteEvent(event){
    if (event.type === "click"){
      event.preventDefault();
      this.props.rmFunc(this.props.name, this.props.quantity);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='PantryRow'>
        <p>Quantity: {this.props.quantity}</p>
        <p>Name: {this.props.name}</p>
        <button
          className="btn btn-default"
          onClick={this.handleDeleteEvent}
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pantry: [{
        name: 'a',
        quantity: 1
      }, {
        name: 'b',
        quantity: 2
      }],
    }
    this.removeFromPantry = this.removeFromPantry.bind(this);
  }
  
  removeFromPantry(name, amount){
    var item = {quantity: amount, name:name};
    var items = this.state.pantry.filter(function(itm){
      return (item.name !== itm.name) && (item.quantity !== itm.quantity);
    });
    this.setState({ pantry: items });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PantryList items={this.state.pantry} rmFunc={this.removeFromPantry} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```